# Run code on Open of an .oft

Tags: vba, outlook

I want the code below to run on Open of an .oft file/email.

I am getting a Runtime 91 error.

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Public EventsDisable As Boolean

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If EventsDisable = True Then Exit Sub
    Set myItem = Item
End Sub


Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    EventsDisable = True
    Dim Insp As Inspector
    Dim obj As Object
    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

    obj.HTMLBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "XXXX", Format(Now + 14, "MMMM dd, yyyy"))

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing

    EventsDisable = False
End Sub
```

If I run the last Sub myItem_Open as a public sub manually it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't have Outlook installed so I can't verify if this is the issue or not, but the `Item` parameter passed to `Application_ItemLoad` isn't always going to be an `Outlook.MailItem`.

Comment: @Comintern Could you be a little more specific? The item itself would be an .oft file. Is that not considered a MailItem? Could you provide an example of how my code should be then?

Comment: Like I said, no Outlook, but it could be [any one of these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861573.aspx). The [documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868544.aspx).

Comment: Ok So after closing and reenabling my macros (went off for some reason) I finally got it to come up in Debug mode. It is the `Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem` that it's throwing the Runtime error on. I don't understand exactly why though. It does run if I run it alone. What's causing it to fail now?

Comment: Looking at your 'anyone one of these' documentation(thank you), would you agree that `IPM.Note` would be best for my uses? And should be declaring `obj as IPM.Note`? I've read the msdn doc, and it's why I'm using the ItemLoad event before my code and private sub. Am I not utilizing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Inspectors.NewInspector` event instead (`Inspectors` can be retrieved from `Application.Inspectors`).

**UPDATE**. Off the top my head

```
Public WithEvents myInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  set  myInspectors = Application.Inspectors
  MsgBox "Application_Startup"
End Sub

Private Sub myInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal insp As Inspector)
    MsgBox "myInspectors_NewInspector"
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem
    obj.HTMLBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "XXXX", Format(Now + 14, "MMMM dd, yyyy"))
    Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following you here. I'm setting Insp. to Application.ActiveInspector. Do I instead need to set it to Application.Inspectors and declare my Dim as Inspectors.NewInspector? @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: There won't be any inspectors until you open an item. You need to subscribe to the Inspectors.NewInspector event. It will fire when an OFT file is open. You can then use the Inspector object passed to the NewInspector event handler and read the Inspector.CurrentItem property. Once you have MailItem object, you can replace the Body property.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Doesn't need to be complex, you can even use my code if it makes it easier for you. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Declare Inspectors variable with events. Provide event handler sub for the Inspectors_NewInspector event the same way you do that for the myItem object.

Comment: Do I need to replace the myItem_Open sub? Is there a site with perhaps a sample code I can see how it's invoked and used in the same manner I wish to utilize it?

Comment: I tried using your code in place of my own. It doesn't fail, but it doesn't do the Replace of the 'xxxx' either. Am I supposed to insert your code at a certain point into my own? Thank you for your time and effort. I know VB but I am very new to Outlook VBA.

Comment: I modified the script above.

Comment: I get a type mismatch at `Set myInspectors = Application.Inspectors`. And it doesn't run on open of the .oft only when I close outlook and then open the .oft. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, myInspectors has to be declared as Outlook.Inspectors (plural).

Comment: Ok I got it to work after making it plural. But it doesn't do the last private sub which does the replace. Do I need call it from another sub above? Sorry for all the follow ups thank you greatly for your help.

Comment: If you just set obj.HTMLBody to an arbitrary text, would that work?

Comment: I tried changing it from a date to "TEST" but it never actually replaces anything. I get the first msg "Application Start up" the second in the last sub never appears. Don't think it's actually running that last sub.

Comment: Replace that line completely. Just set the HTMLBody property to something like "<b>bold</b> text" to see if it is setting the body or replacing that fails.

Comment: Ok so after testing and fiddling with Outlook, I figured out it's not working on open of the .oft, but rather only when I click a "New Message". Not exactly what I'm shooting for. I need it to fire on open of the .oft template.

Comment: NewInspector might not fire when a message is opened using Simple MAPI and in a few other cases... You could use a timer to periodically scan the Application.Inspectors collection and check if there is a new inspector, but I don't think you can use a timer in VBA.

Comment: Is there a way to initialize an inspector on load? So If I were to open the file then the first or second sub initialize the inspector, would it then be able to read the object and replace what's needed?

Comment: No, NewInspector is the only event that fires when an inspector is opened.